# Using UWP library on WPF Platform (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, webrtc

I would like to use the UWP library ([WebRTC UWP](https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc-windows) Library) on my WPF project. How can I convert this library into WPF platform (x86 or x64)? Thanks for advice

Comment: There are other WebRTC libraries for .NET, which you can learn from Google.

Comment: @IshamMohamed I've been adding this nuget package into my wpf project but is called error "Could not install package 'WebRtc 1.54.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." How can I do that?

Comment: @LexLi Could you give some example library webrtc for .NET. I've been searching but it cannot use but on this UWP library it's work.

Comment: not uwp but avspeed has a wpf control that uses webrtc https://avspeed.github.io/ . They have a demo on github https://github.com/avspeed/AppRTCWPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't use a UWP-only library with anything but a UWP project.

A NuGet package must target a framework that is compatible with your project type.

If you crack open the nupkg, you'd see under the lib folder, it has `uap` folder which means it targeted only at UWP projects.

Now, if it has a `net452` or a similar folder under lib, then it could have been consumed by WPF and theoretically other .NET framework projects running .NET Framework version 4.5.2 and above, in this example.